# How we can notify if Android webview content changed (without reload URL)

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have a load URL in webView in Android native app, After page loaded into webView if admin has changed the page content from backend, now i want to show notification to user for the content has been changed.

I want to implement the content change listener (to get notify when content has changed) without refresh webview URL.

is it possible anyway?

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call webView.reload() but be aware this reposts a page
    if the request was POST, so only works correctly with GET.

```
  webView.reload()
```

Comment: I don't want to reload webView.
Basically, i just want to show a notification to user only if the content of current webview page has been changed. 

without refresh page.

Comment: in that case, the admin sends notification in an application. webview doesn't generate a notification on content refresh.